# What is wrong with this code that shows a flipping coin, also how can I show this animation in the centre of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

```
 imageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "3039668.png")!,    
 UIImage(named: "3039651.png")!]
     imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
     imageView.animationRepeatCount = 10
     imageView.startAnimating()
```

Here is my code, I am new to swift so please forgive any silly mistakes. If you can answer even one point in the question please do

Comment: To those who downvote : explain why you do so, otherwise it is pointless. Bodi you need to post more code, to let us have a better idea of what is going on. In the middle of the screen : you use the view.frame.size.width/2 , and the same thing for the height, for the center variable of your imageview. Or you use constraints : horizontal and vertical : you can do so with the settings in the storyboard.

Comment: Hi I am trying to animate a coin turning from head to tails, the two images are of the two faces of a coin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I tried and it works for me :

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImage(named: "img1.png")
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        let uiTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"myHandle")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(uiTap)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    func myHandle(){
        imageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "img1.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "img2.png")!]
        imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
        imageView.animationRepeatCount = 10
        imageView.startAnimating()
    }

}
```

Try and see if something is different from this code with yours.